# How to Draw 2D Shapes in DirectX

Tags: 2d, directx

I am currently trying to **draw a simple 2D circle and an arc in DirectX** but there are no resources online with info on how I can do this. Lines & Points are built into DirectX anyway so that has never been a problem.

Can somebody explain how I can do this? I'm not talking about a sphere or any other 3D geometry. **Just a simple 2D Circle and Arc.**

[image]

Comment: Can you draw 3d stuff?

Comment: @Bálint Yeah, Cubes with Textures, Diffuse & Specular reflections etc. Haven't moved on to other types of geometry yet because I'm trying to implement SSAO and other rendering techniques at the moment. But I don't imagine 2D being hard at all.

Comment: Then drawing circles is just drawing a lot of triangles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to approximate these shapes with triangles. Assembling a circle from triangles can be done like the following pseudo-code:

```
list<Vector2> vertices;
float radius = 10;
vertices.Add(Vector2(0,0)) // center point
for (float i = 0; i <= 100; i += 1.0f)
{
    float t = PI * 2 * i / 100;
    vertices.Add(Vector2(radius * cos(t), radius * -sin(t)));
}
```

Then you can draw these vertices with a triangle fan primitive topology.

Answer (score 0):

You could draw a quad and use a pixel shader to fill the circle/arc.